# Can I download my code from Keil uVision5 or STM32CubeIDE to the STM32F103C6T6 board via FTDI?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, ftdi, stm32cubemx, keil

Can I download my code from Keil uVision5 or STM32CubeIDE to the STM32F103C6T6 board via FTDI? If yes, then how should I do it? I can't find anything that helps online.
If there is no method to do so with these two IDEs, is there any other IDE (except Arduino IDE because I want to learn advanced programming and stay away from Arduino) that will help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You can upload the application using another program, called STM32CubeProg. It's a device programming software and supports Serial or USB-DFU modes. you'll need an USB-Serial adapter (e.g. ftdi or ch340) and proper booting of your microcontroller. you have to read [AN2606](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwicxJSNjMP1AhVsh_0HHVhYA4EQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fapplication_note%2Fcd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2NOadXCCHepnPpgQX1P-ho) to understand bootloader options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, the answer of @Tirdad Sadri Nejad is correct. Let me elaborate a little.

You need STM32CubeProgrammer, which can upload compiled binary to the board. In order to upload firmware via UART, you will have to switch BOOT0 pin/switch to 1 (and reset/power cycle of course). In order to run the code, you will need to switch BOOT0 to  0 and reset as well.

BOOT0 set to 1 on power-on will activate built-in fixed booloader, which is a program designed to, well, program the MCU (it's a whole another independent piece of memory that can't be edited). It can work with UART or other protocols (it's even possible for some STM32 to be flashed via I2C!)

[image: stm32cubeprogrammer]

This is STM32CubeProgrammer. I don't use it because I have ST-Link on my Disco Board, and the error is there because I tried to connect without activating bootloader (switching BOOT0 to 1). Anyway, on the top-right you can select "UART", and you'll be able to access the flash memory of the MCU. All you need is to compile your program, open the binary file with "Open File", then choose "Download" option where you see "Read" (yes, it's "download", it freaks me out too).

Honestly, switching BOOT0 to 1 to flash it and then to 0 to run it every time is annoying. You should get a standalone ST-Link, it's a one time purchase that improves quality of life immesurably. Also, it will allow you to use very cool debugger where you can literally stop program execution on any line of code you want and check what variables are, see registers at any moment etc. Very useful. Even if you don't need all that functionality now, you probably will eventually, and you don't need to physically switch BOOT0. When you write your first code and just blink LED and need to switch BOOT0 every 3 minutes, it gets very annoying.

Also, with ST-Link you can upload firmware straight from the IDE.